# How to run MsBuild with specific target when publishing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I've added a target section to my csproj file like this.

```
<Target Name="Spa">
  <Exec Command="ng --version" WorkingDirectory="../Spa" />
  <Exec Command="ng build --prod" WorkingDirectory="../Spa" />
  <Exec Command="del .\wwwroot\* /F /Q /S" />
  <Exec Command="copy ..\Spa\dist\Spa\* .\wwwroot" />
</Target>
```

When I'm executing it using the command below, it does precisely what it's supposed to.

```
dotnet msbuild /t:Spa
```

However, it'd be nice if the target could be invoked just prior to the execution of publishing within Visual Studio (<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

I've read [somewhere](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/10/12/how-to-beyond-prebuild-and-postbuild-steps/) that it's possible and [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) claim that *BeforePublish* is the correct target name. However, when I change the name *Spa* to *BeforePublish*, I'm not getting the effect of my SPA being built and copied over.

What am I missing and how do I automate the process?

Comment: Maybe try adding a BeforeTargets="BeforePublish" to the target? Or add a DefaultTargets="Build, Spa" to the project file?

Comment: Quick santity check, Make sure your BeforePublish target is defined at the bottom of your csproj.

Comment: @MichaelBaker I didn't think of the order (in fact I've read somewhere that it's of no significance) but as it happens, it was at the bottom already. Good hint. Regrettably, already in effect. Got more thoughts?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Just so I don't get lost in confusion - would you mind posting a quick sample of what you mean? I'm a bit unclear on where the *DefaultTargets* should go. As an attribute to the target section? (*BeforeTargets* is an attribute in said tag, I imagine, so I'll test that right away.)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Nevermind that, by the way. It worked now that I added *BeforeTargets*. Must be a change in VS 2017. According to the docs for previous version, naming the target by the step, piggy-backs on it. Apparently, it needs to be explicitly specified now and the name matters not. Please post your comment as a reply so I can accept it as an answer. Make sure to add the comment of Michael about placement of the target section in the file (at the bottom, he said). Also, you might want to add the remark about older versions.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Also, it seems that the info I've seen was correct - the requirement that the target section is at the bottom of the csproj file seems to be superfluous, at least in my this case. I just moved the target section to the top of the csproj file and it works still. Might be good to add that remark as well. The comments will be removed eventually and god knows what MS might have done under the hood. Your call, of course. I'm just speaking my mind.

Comment: the position of targets usually only mattered for old style csproj when e.g. a `BeforeBuild` target was defined both in the project and common targets which would overwrite one another - if you use the (sort of) new `BeforeTargets`/`AfterTargets` it doesn't matter.

Comment: Depends how the author of the hook point implemented it and expected it to be overridden. If you use Before/After or DependsOn then order is irreverent. If you are doing target replacement then order definitely matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to run MsBuild with specific target when publishing?

I post an answer here to make sure this question more clear.

For this question, The **first thing** to note is that it is related to the project type. If you are publish a WPF/Winodws Forms project, the `<Target Name="BeforePublish ">` should be works as expected. That because these project types include the target `publish` by default, so the target "BeforePublish" will work as expected.

However, the web project not contain this default target `Publish`, so if you use `<Target Name="BeforePublish ">` in the web project, it will not executed as expected. **To resolve this issue**, we could add a `BeforeTargets="BeforePublish"` to the target, like:

```
<Target Name="Spa" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
   ...
</Target>
```

Then Overriding "DependsOn" Properties:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      BeforeBuild;
      CoreBuild;
      AfterBuild;
      BeforePublish
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**Or** you can simple add `AfterTargets="Build"` to the target `Spa`, it should woks fine:

```
<Target Name="Spa" AfterTargets="Build">
   ...
</Target>
```

The **second thing** to note is that whether the target section needs to be at the bottom of the csproj file is depends on the style csproj. Just as Martin said, if you are in the old style csproj, those targets `BeforeBuild`, `AfterBuild` are actually pre-defined in the `Microsoft.Common.targets` file that contains the Visual Studio Build process, so we have to set our custom target at the bottom of the csproj to overwrite it in the `Microsoft.Common.targets` file. If you are in the new style csproj(), it doesn't matter where you set it.

Hope this helps.